# QLineEdit onVisible() causes crash in debug in QT

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt 4.7.0 (32 bit) on Windows(mingw32).

The app is crashing when setVisible(),setDisabled(),hide() and show() are called. Official documentation, forums and google haven't helped so far. The QLineEdit variable is declared in the xml (passwordEdit).

The crash occurs only in debug mode, not in release mode.

```
 ui->passwordEdit->setVisible(false);
```

Comment: _What_ crash do you get? Could you please add the exact error (or errors) to the question?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not getting any error message in qt. Only a run time terminatin message in windows. When I stepped into the setVisible function, found that it is crashing in the line d->show_helper(); in QWidget.cpp (line number 7589)

Comment: Okay, but what do the message in the dialog say then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Windows says this: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application support team for more help.. I guess this is a general error.. I'm not getting anything from QT though.

Comment: Probably an assertion evaluated to false.This only line is not going to help.

Comment: @UmNyobe I checked now there aren't any assertions in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app was crashing because I was updating widgets' visibility and other properties from another thread. I didn't realize you have to do it from within the GUI thread. Using [postEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) solved the problem.